# Can't get the laravel custom repository to work

Tags: laravel, eloquent, repository, repository-pattern

I can't get my repository working, when i'm just trying the get the entire list of documents it returns nothing

Here's my DocumentRepository

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Document;

interface DocumentRepository
{
  public function getall();

  public function getById($id);

  public function create(array $attributes);

  public function update ($id, array $attributes);

  public function delete ($id);

}
```

Here's the functions

```
<?php


namespace App\Repositories\Document;

class EloquentDocument implements DocumentRepository
{

  private $model;

  public function __construct(Document $model)
  {
    $this->model = $model;
  }


  public function getall()
  {
    return $this->model->all();
  }

  public function getById($id)
  {
    return $this->findById($id);
  }

  public function create(array $attributes)
  {
    return $this->model->create($attributes);
  }

  public function delete($id)
  {
    $this->getById($id)->delete();
    return true;
  }

  public function update($id array $attributes)
  {
    $document = $this->model->findOrFail($id);
    $document->update($attribute);
    return $document;
  }
}
```

and here's the controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\Document;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DocumentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var DocumentRepository
     */
    private $document;
    /**
     * TodoController constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(DocumentController $document)
    {
        $this->document = $document;
    }
    public function getalldocuments()
    {
        return $this->document->getAll();
    }
}
```

For your information there's two rows of data in my Documents table/model so i just want to get both of them by just simply returning but in my case it simply returns nothing.
Here's the route

```
Route::get('/documents', 'DocumentController@getalldocuments');
```

here's the registration part insite AppServiceProviders.php

```
 public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(DocumentRepository::class, EloquentDocument::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are type-hinting `DocumentController` instead of your actual repository.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Repositories\Document\DocumentRepository; 

class DocumentController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * @var DocumentRepository
    */
    private $document;

    public function __construct(DocumentRepository $document)
    {
        $this->document = $document;
    }

    public function getalldocuments()
    {
        return $this->document->getAll();
    }
}
```

Now, assuming you have properly binded the interface to resolve to your document repository implemented, this should work.

For more information on how to bind interfaces to implementation, read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations

**Edit**: You have some syntax issues in your repository's interface. You are missing *function*:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Document;

interface DocumentRepository
{
  public function getall();

  public function getById($id);

  public function create(array $attributes);

  public function update($id, array $attributes);

  public function delete($id);
}
```

**Edit 2:** Your binding is correct. However, I noticed that you are not binding your `App\Document` model to the implementation correctly.

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Document;

use App\Document; 

class EloquentDocument implements DocumentRepository
{

    private $model;

    public function __construct(Document $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    //
    //
    //
}
```

You need to add the correct use statement at the top. Assuming your document model resides in `App\Document` this should work.

Comment: I get an error like dis
Class App\Repositories\Document\DocumentRepository does not exist
Previous exceptions

    syntax error, unexpected 'update' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) (0)

Comment: You are missing the keyword *function* while defining your methods. See edited answer.

Comment: fixed it now i'm getting  ReflectionException Class App\Repositories\Document\Document does not exist

:(((

Comment: Could you edit your answer to add the service provider where you are binding the interface to the implementation?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: HOLY MOTHER OF GOD, I GOT IT WORKING. THANK YOU SENPAI I OWE YOU ONE :))) <3 ^_^